# Understand when a button is really clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Hi guys i have a google chrome extension that performs a click on a button

```
document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();
```

that add an item to the basket and after i do a redirect to the checkout page , the problem is that if i do the redirect too early it's like as the item hasn't been sended to basket. Is there a way to undestand when the item has been effectively inserted into the basket and than redirecting?

Comment: share some more code if you are looking for a detailed explanation.
In general, you should have a way to monitor the cart, wait for an item to get added to the basket and then redirect. You can watch that element for changes (Mutation Observer)

Comment: Hi thk for you answer, now i'm using that code i posted to click the button than using delay to wait 800ms and then redirect to the page of the basket. Unfortunatly if the websites lag 800ms aren't enough and when i redirect to the basket there aren't item in it

Comment: Like I said, check out the mutation observers. Using that you will be able to monitor the cart object and when it changes you can trigger the click

Comment: You can always use a loop, run every x ms, (100?) and check if you can redirect, and if you can - you do, otherwise you wait for the next iteration.